# PHP - Search value in sub array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have two arrays that have to be migrated.

```
    $products = array(
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #1',
             'sku'     => 53159,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         ),
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #2',
             'sku'     => 60290,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         ),
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #3',
             'sku'     => 24195,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         )
    );

    $similar_products = array(
        array(25195, 53159),
        array(60290, 33619),
        array(80001, 24195)
    );
```

I wan't to build a final array with the following result:

```
    $final= array(
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #1',
             'sku'     => 53159,
             'similar' => 25195,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         ),
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #2',
             'sku'     => 60290,
             'similar' => 33619,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         ),
         array(
             'title'   => 'Product #3',
             'sku'     => 24195,
             'similar' => 80001,
             'price'   => 12,
             'image'   => 'product_01.jpg'
         )
    );
```

I tried to find the similar skus with **in_array** inside a **foreach loop**:

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {

    foreach ( $similar_products as $similar_product) {
    
       if ( in_array( $product['sku'] ,$similar_product) ) {
           // Build the $final array here
       }
    
    }

}
```

but it's taking too long.

I there any other method to help me getting faster the similar sku?

Comment: Taking too long? How many entries do you have? Then I would hardly suggest using a database.

Comment: The code you have shown does not make sense to begin with, trying to access `$product[1]` should give you an undefined index.

Comment: It should not work with that update either. You are comparing a numeric value, with _arrays_ containing two numbers each - so that should never find anything either.

Comment: Is this a 1:1 relation, or can there be _multiple_ similar products for one SKU? (And if so, what would you want the result to look like then?)

Comment: @CBroe thanks again, didn't notice, updated. It's 1:1 relation, yes.

Comment: Then I would transform this to an array, that has one SKU as the key, and the other one as the value. (In both "directions" -  `array(25195, 53159)` has to become `25195 => 53159` and `53159 => 25195`.) Then you can do the "look-up" of an SKU simply via `isset($similar_products[$product['sku']]);` - that is usually way faster, than looping yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$final = $products;
foreach ($similar_products as [$similar, $sku]) {
    $index = array_search($sku, array_column($final, 'sku'));
    if (false === $index) {
        $index                    = array_search($similar, array_column($final, 'sku'));
        $final[$index]['similar'] = $sku;
        continue;
    }
    $final[$index]['similar'] = $similar;
}
```

Final looks like Demo: https://3v4l.org/1Dl62/perf

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Product #1
            [sku] => 53159
            [price] => 12
            [image] => product_01.jpg
            [similar] => 25195
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Product #2
            [sku] => 60290
            [price] => 12
            [image] => product_01.jpg
            [similar] => 33619
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Product #3
            [sku] => 24195
            [price] => 12
            [image] => product_01.jpg
            [similar] => 80001
        )

)
```